# Chromecast Orientation

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to build a google cast app that will be put in use on buses. I have the shape of the bus on a Nexus 7 in portrait mode, but I want to show the screen in landscape mode on my TV. So the shape of the bus should be 90 degrees rotated but the letters straight up.

This is not a video, just a frame with infos about the bus. Is this something possible with Chromecast?

Thank you in advance. Have a great one!

Best Regards

Comment: It is definitely possible on the Chromecast. Perhaps you should share what code you already have and then the people may help you better.

Comment: This is just plain CSS3 transformations, and nothing specific to Chromecast: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform ... to be precise: there is to my knowledge no portrait mode, if this is what you're asking for. You are just creating an HTML page with CSS transformations that rotate your text by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Chromecast provides a 720p graphics plane that you can render in any HTML technologies you want. You can use pure HTML with CSS or you can render graphics using a canvas or even WebGL. It is up to you to do the rotation. A chromecast receiver is essentially a web app that behaves like a single tab in a Chrome browser.